# I need to email the users of my site but my host does not support many emailings per hour

Tags: email

I have a security concern on my site and I need to inform my users about it via their stored email addresses. However, my host does not allow for huge numbers of emails. What are my options?

Comment: Send a message to all of them in one go, not one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send the emails out from your server, but it's likely that you'll have a high false positive spam rate. I'd just sign up for a Mailchimp account. That's going to be your quickest way to get your message out in a reliable fashion.

Comment: Will Mailchimp not result in a high spamrate?

Comment: They're in the business of email delivery. I guarantee you, they'll get a higher delivery rate than you could ever dream of getting.

Comment: @user3763670 The reason mails sent directly from your server might be marked as spam is IP reputation. You have none so a sudden burst of email from that IP is probably spam. Mailchimp (and others like them) already have IPs with good reputations that already send a lot of email.

Comment: Since Email Service Providers like MailChimp monitor sent emails and put a hold on high bounce-rate email blasts, they are trusted to bulk mail such stuff. Your untrusted server is more likely to be considered a high spamrate source. You could even sign up with Amazon and use their Simple Mail Service, but sending bulk from them requires a train-in period where they reduce the send rate and monitor for high-bounce activity which indicates spamming.